# SQL query using AJAX in Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, ajax, wordpress

I'm attempting to use AJAX to insert data into a database, but am unable to connect to the .php file on the server end. I'm thinking this is due to the fact that this is all run on Wordpress, so my normal url path to the .php file might not be correct.

Here is my setup:

Template file:

```
$('#newsletter-register').submit(function(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "register_newsletter.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);

});
```

'#newsletter-register' is form that the user will use to submit his/her information. The alert when the ajaxRequest is at readyState 4 is thrown correctly, but will an empty value.

My php is a simple echo returning a string to signal that the connection is correct (presently I'm just trying to see if the files are correctly calling eachother).

I'm thinking it must be the url path to register_newsletter.php as I've tried placing the code within the template file, outside, etc.

My javascript file is located in /theme/assets/js/code.js where as my template files (including the register_newsletter.php file) in /theme.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not directly related to the question, but it seems like you're using jQuery, so you don't need to define your own `ajaxRequest` - you can just use `$.ajax()`!

Comment: that's well worth noting, thanks andre_roesti!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this type of issue yesterday. In my situation the page would only be accessed from

```
www.site.com/aFolder/
```

The script was stored in my

```
'/wp-content/themes/themeName/processForm.php'
```

folder.

and the URL I used was:

```
../wp-content/themes/themeName/processForm.php
```

My JS was simply in the head of the main header.php file, but note that the URL I had to use was relative to the URL the page the script was accessed from.
Does that shed any light on things?

EDIT:

As troubleshooting steps, try ensuring you can access your php file from it's absolute URL, and have a look in firebug to see what link is being called when you fire the ajax request to see if it matches up with what you expect.

Comment: I think this is where I don't understand - ok so I've added my script to the my header.php file so it's now inline as you've done. The header.php is included in the pages that contain the form. As my .php file that will process the form is in the same directory as yours (/wp-content/themes/themeName/processForm.php), I've added your URL aswell when calling the .php file through AJAX (../wp-content/themes/themeName/processForm.php). I don't understand though why it has to be 'relative to the URL the page the script was accessed from' or what you mean by this.

Comment: What I meant by the comment is that the header.php file is included in each page, and those pages can be accessed (with permalinks) from site.com/ or site.com/pageName (for example). When you are making your ajax request you need to make it from the context of the calling page (the url you are using to view the page). In my example I needed to go back one directory to from from www.site.com/pageName back to www.site.com and then up /wp-content/themes/themename/processForm.php. This is relative to URL which is active at the point you make the ajax request, rather than the original file location

Comment: If your script is located in the theme directory, you can just use `bloginfo('theme_directory')` as path for the script. But because `readyState = 4` is triggered, the path of your script probably isn't the problem.

Comment: the readyState = 4 seems to be triggered even if I call a non-existant .php file. I've followed the steps from a site to creating an AJAX script, and I can't find any faulty logic in my code, but I agree that the readyState shouldn't be = 4, as it is.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald To your edit, I can't access the .php file using its absolute URL. it gives me the php error that no such file exists. I assumed this was because I couldn't access the .php files directely from its absolute path as it's tied into Wordpress. So to answer to your edit, this would be an error I would need to resolve. Do you know how?